# Issue in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the text file with below content

```
SCREEN_NAME
bdaff
sakassim
test
```

The below code is running , in the checknode function , the variable print(x[1])
displaying the screen name ,properly. But when i am using the value in cypher variable, its shows 1,2,3(set the result at end)

Please help..

```
d = read.table("c:/sajudentick/tm/neoTest.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "")

checkNode <- function(x, graph, type) {
  #print(x[1])
  name1<-x[1]
  print(typeof(name1))
  print(name1)

  cipher<-  paste0("MATCH (n:",type, ") WHERE n.username  IN ['" ,name1 , 
                   "'] RETURN n")
  print(cipher)
  node_gr <- getNodes(graph,cipher)
  print(is.null(node_gr))
  if (is.null(node_gr)) {
    print("created")
    node_gr <- createNode(graph = graph, .label = type, x)
    #graph, "User", username=screenName
  }

  return(node_gr)

}

people_nodes <- d %>% by_row(checkNode, graph = graph, type = "User")



[1] "list"
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  value
  <fct>
1 bdaff
[1] "MATCH (n:User) WHERE n.username  IN ['1'] RETURN n"
[1] FALSE
[1] "list"
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  value   
  <fct>   
1 sakassim
[1] "MATCH (n:User) WHERE n.username  IN ['2'] RETURN n"
[1] FALSE
[1] "list"
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  value
  <fct>
1 test 
[1] "MATCH (n:User) WHERE n.username  IN ['3'] RETURN n"
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
checkNode <- function(x, graph, type) {
  #print(x[1])
  name1<-x[1]
```

Assuming you wanted to get the value of a variable from a data frame, that should be `x[[1]]`.